# Simple Present in Indefinite Past timeI

Tags: tense

My grammar book says Simple Present can be used with some certain verbs in **Indefinite Past**

For example,

"I forget what he said"

Is there any difference between

"I forgot what he said" and "I forget what he said"

Because Simple past can also express "Uncertain  Past" in this case

Comment: You need to consider the context around such statement.

Comment: @user3169 would you mind to give a context example when can I say "I forget what he said" instead of "I forgot what he said"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spoken English, "I forget" is most commonly used as a very informal way of saying "I forgot". This is very common in casual conversation:

> A: Do we have homework this week?
>
> B: I don't know, I forget what the teacher said.

You could use "I forget (x)" to indicate that you *always* or *habitually* forget something, but then you would want to use the present tense in the inner clause, and probably use some modifier, like *always*:

> John is such an unmemorable speaker. I always forget what he says.

"I forget what he said" could mean that you habitually forget one thing that he said at a particular time in the past: e.g.

> I always forget what John said on that one August night. He gave me some advice, but I can never remember it.